# How would you make the text in a checkbox cell be able to be edited?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-data

How would you make the text in a check box cell able to be edited like in a text cell instead of it just checking the Checkbox? The thing is that the Checkbox is Boolean in the Core Data Model and the Text is a String, so I don't know how I would make this work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have two columns: One with a checkbox cell and the other with a text cell, each bound to the appropriate property of your model objects.

Comment: Thats what I had first, but it didn't look that great. Are you sure it's not possible to do it using a checkbox cell?

Comment: Yes. NSButton and NSButtonCell don't support editing their text. (Look at the documentation.) You can make a custom cell if you want to improve on the look; just be warned that it's a lot of work.

Answer (score 0):

Why use checkbox? The checkbox is designed to have two values only as you say. Therefore, you can try other controls, such as input area and so on. What I mean is that you can't make the rectangle to roll because it can't roll at all, right?

Comment: The cell is in an outline view. Not on it's own.

Comment: And what do you mean by roll.